# Laravel + Vue 2 how to run certain functions on different pages

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-routing

I am having this confussion, I have functions `getUsers()` and `getCategories()` (for instance) to retrieve all the users and categories in their respective pages `/admin/users` & `/admin/categories`.

I have a table where I load the users and in the other page another table to load the categories.

I was told to use them in **created** hook like:

```
created: function() {
    this.getUsers();
    this.getCategories();
}
```

But this causes those functions to load in the same page, I think this is unnecesary (maybe when I have 1 million records).

So I think what I need is to run `this.getUsers()` when I am on `/admin/users` and `this.getCategories()` when I am on `/admin/categories`.

> **Note:** I am not using *Vue-Router*. Instead, I am using **Laravel Routing**

What should I do?

Comment: How do you manage routing if not using a router?

Comment: @connexo, as the specified tag, I am using Laravel Routing.

Comment: But that's server-side, no? I used to think of Vue.js as being an SPA framework.

Comment: According to [Vue.js Documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) it's not only for SPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
created: function() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    if(path === '/admin/users')
        this.getUsers();
    else if(path === '/admin/categories')
        this.getCategories();
}
```

Comment: is this like a convention? like what should be used in all the projects ever?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean if you commonly when designing a web application use what you wrote here.

Comment: um no. the normal practice is to use vue-router. but your routing is based on your laravel backend, so you can only get the route info though `window.location` in JS. I dunno laravel so i dunno what's the best practice when using vue with laravel

Comment: I should change that. Laravel comes with Vue.js as default JS framework.